# CSS Functionality with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'll try this again.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to work with the Datatables plugin for jQuery in the fact that I need for example if there are 3 numbered page links which would have the First, Previous, Next, Last links as well. If you were on page 1 then the First, Previous buttons should only have the pagination_button_disabled css applied to it but instead it ALSO has the paginate button and then the first or previous css style as well. I just want the first and last to have a css style of paginate_button_disabled if you are on page 1 and obviously revered if you were on page 3 then Last and Next should be disabled.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rx8se/

The pagination links should be like this: http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/manager/index2.html

Notice the prev button is disabled css  and how its crossed out of the jsfiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datatables Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684473/datatables-plugin)

Comment: Seems like I can't get any help from anywhere.

Comment: if you add more info (snippet of your code, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com/) (demo)), it will help others to determine what the problem is

Comment: I have updated my post to include the jfiddle.net coding of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I also agree that this question is unreadable in its current form, what little I can understand of it seems to describe verbatim the effects of the demo on the "dataTables > Development > Pagination" [example](http://www.datatables.net/development/pagination).

It includes 4 button pagination (first, previous, next, last) with classes applied appropriately to disable functionality of unusable buttons.

Comment: Right but if you notice it has the disabled styles crossed off when it shouldn't because with the table having no data then all 4 of those buttons should be disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really going to need to have a working example to see what you mean.

Comment: Well this is my personal CMS. Is there something I can email you login information.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the links. The fiddle does nothing, and the "admin panel" has no datatable...

Comment: Could you send me an email and I can talk to you about this outside of here. xtremer360@yahoo.com